# Merging two sorted lists returns Runtime Error

Tags: python, list, sorting, merge

I am trying to solve a problem which asks for merging two sorted linked lists. Although my code passes most tests, it does not do well with large inputs, very long linked lists. What can i improve? Thanks!
This is my code:

```
#
# For your reference:
#
# SinglyLinkedListNode:
#     int data
#     SinglyLinkedListNode next
#
#
def mergeLists(head1, head2):
    if head1 is None:
        return head2
    if head2 is None:
        return head1

    p1=head1
    p2=head2
    while head1.data >= p2.data:
        nxt = p2.next
        p2.next = head1
        head1 = p2
        p2 = nxt
    p1 = head1
    while p1 is not None and p2 is not None:

        if p1.data <= p2.data and (p1.next is None or p1.next.data >= p2.data):

            next2 = p2.next
            p2.next = p1.next
            p1.next = p2
            p2 = next2



        p1 = p1.next
    return head1
```

Comment: What's the exact complete error?

Comment: @zerkms i am resolving this problem on a site and "runtime error" is the only information provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are do a lot of duplicate assignments, as well as duplicate checks. I tried to write a code with a minimal amount of both. Of course, if the goal was to write easy-to-read code, then a recursive algorithm would be the best solution. But not in our case. Also note that it makes no sense to check the sentinel on two lists at the same time, since the length of the lists is unknown and can be different at any time.

```
class L(object):
    __slots__ = 'data', 'next'

    def __repr__(self): # just for tests
        return f'{self.data!r}, {self.next!r}'

    def __eq__(self, other): # just for tests
        return (self.data == other.data) and (self.next == other.next)

def merge0(a: L, b: L, sentinel=None):
    if a is sentinel:
        return b
    if b is sentinel:
        return a

    if a.data > b.data:
        head = last = b
        b = b.next
    else:
        head = last = a
        a = a.next

    while True:
        if a.data > b.data:
            last.next = last = b
            if (b := b.next) is sentinel:
                last.next = a
                return head
        else:
            last.next = last = a
            if (a := a.next) is sentinel:
                last.next = b
                return head
```

The code above operates with 6 main pointers:

- `a` - the head of first linked list. `a.next` can be `sentinel`;
- `b` - the head of second linked list. `b.next` can be `sentinel`;
- `head` - the head of new merged linked list. It is either `a` or `b`. Not useful during the main loop;
- `last` - the current last object of new merged linked list. Initially is `head`;
- `last.next` - this pointer is undefined during the main loop. It can be `a`, `b`, `a.next` or `b.next`;
- `sentinel` - unique singleton object that marks the end of any linked list.

Each step of the loop, we find out smaller element and assign it to `last.next`. Then we create new `last` and check out possible end of the list with this element. Then the loop repeats.

However, this is still not an optimal algorithm. Imagine that we have `ll1(0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8)`, `ll2(6, 7, 9, 10)` and merged `ll(0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10)`. In fact, the first 5 elements of `ll` are the five elements of the `ll1`. According to the `merge0` main loop, each of these elements (except the first) has been reassigned to its left neighbor. The inefficiency of this approach is especially notable when merged lists have a large spread in values.

Secondly, it would be nice to replace the explicit check of sentinel of each list. The `sentinel` object doesn't have to be `None` and may be implemented as a custom object with a native exception throwing mechanism.

Improved version:

```
@object.__new__
class sentinel(object):
    __slots__ = ()

    @property
    def next(self):
        raise self.Signal()

    @property
    def data(self):
        raise self.Signal()

    class Signal(Exception):
        pass

    def __eq__(self, other):  # just for tests
        return (other is self) or (other is None)

def merge1(a: L, b: L, sentinel=sentinel):
    if a is sentinel:
        return b
    if b is sentinel:
        return a

    if a.data <= b.data:
        head = x = a
        y = b
    else:
        head = x = b
        y = a

    try:
        while True:
            while (x := (last := x).next).data <= y.data:
                pass
            last.next = y
            while (y := (last := y).next).data <= x.data:
                pass
            last.next = x
    except sentinel.Signal:
        last.next = y if (x is sentinel) else x
        return head
```

Some test-related code:

```
def random_sorted_ll(length, min_num, span, sentinel=None):
    """creates sorted linked list of random integers"""
    assert length >= 1
    from random import randint
    from itertools import repeat

    head = last = L()
    head.data = d = randint(min_num, min_num + span)
    ll_factory = map(L.__new__, repeat(L, length-1))
    for l in ll_factory:
        last.next = last = l
        l.data = d = randint(d, d+span)

    last.next = sentinel
    # last.data should be close to (length * span / 2 + min_num)
    return head

def copy_ll(head, prev_sentinel=None, new_sentinel=None):
    """creates deepcopy of given linked list head with new sentinel"""
    if head is prev_sentinel:
        return new_sentinel
    head_copy = last = L()
    last.data = head.data
    head = head.next
    while head is not prev_sentinel:
        last.next = last = L()
        last.data = head.data
        head = head.next
    last.next = new_sentinel
    return head_copy
```

Some tests:

```
>>> j0 = random_sorted_ll(length=100, min_num=4, span=5)
>>> j1 = copy_ll(j0)
>>> j2 = copy_ll(j0, prev_sentinel=None, new_sentinel=sentinel)
>>> k0 = random_sorted_ll(length=111, min_num=4, span=5)
>>> k1 = copy_ll(k0)
>>> k2 = copy_ll(k0, prev_sentinel=None, new_sentinel=sentinel)
>>> (j0 == j1 == j2) and (k0 == k1 == k2)
True
>>> m0 = mergeLists(j0, k0)
>>> m1 = merge0(j1, k1)
>>> m2 = merge1(j2, k2)
>>> m0 == m1 == m2
True
>>> (m2 is j2) or (m2 is k2)
True
```

Comparisons:

```
def compare_speed(len0, len1, mn0, mn1, span0, span1):
    print(f'\nll in an approximate range ({mn0:_d}, {len0*span0//2+mn0:_d}) with {len0=:_d}')
    j0 = random_sorted_ll(len0, mn0, span0)
    j1 = copy_ll(j0)
    j2 = copy_ll(j0, None, sentinel)
    print(f'll in an approximate range ({mn1:_d}, {len1*span1//2+mn1:_d}) with {len1=:_d}')
    k0 = random_sorted_ll(len1, mn1, span1)
    k1 = copy_ll(k0)
    k2 = copy_ll(k0, None, sentinel)
    from timeit import timeit

    print('mergeLists:', timeit((lambda: mergeLists(j0, k0)), number=1), 'sec')
    print('merge0:', timeit((lambda: merge0(j1, k1)), number=1), 'sec')
    print('merge1:', timeit((lambda: merge1(j2, k2)), number=1), 'sec')

compare_speed(1_111_111, 1_000_000, 0, 0, 5, 5)
compare_speed(1_111_111, 1_000_000, 0, -25_000_000, 5, 100)
compare_speed(9_000_000, 9_111_111, 0, 0, 5, 5)
```

My results:

```
ll in an approximate range (0, 2_777_777) with len0=1_111_111
ll in an approximate range (0, 2_500_000) with len1=1_000_000
mergeLists: 0.46664454099999997 sec
merge0: 0.2180013780000003 sec
merge1: 0.16215903499999996 sec

ll in an approximate range (0, 2_777_777) with len0=1_111_111
ll in an approximate range (-25_000_000, 25_000_000) with len1=1_000_000
mergeLists: 0.4489969129999736 sec
merge0: 0.16649408400007815 sec
merge1: 0.1128580580000289 sec

ll in an approximate range (0, 22_500_000) with len0=9_000_000
ll in an approximate range (0, 22_777_777) with len1=9_111_111
mergeLists: 4.245676940000003 sec
merge0: 1.9906823259999982 sec
merge1: 1.548923153000004 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we do a merge operation by constructing a new list rather than modifying existing nodes:

```
def merge(p1, p2):
    while p1 is not None and p2 is not None:
        if p1.data < p2.data:
            yield p1.data
            p1 = p1.next
        else:
            yield p2.data
            p2 = p2.next

    while p1 is not None:
        yield p1.data
        p1 = p1.next

    while p2 is not None:
        yield p2.data
        p2 = p2.next

def mergeLists(p1, p2):
    return list(merge(p1, p2))
```

(Instead of `yield`, you can also `.append()` to a temporary list.)

If you *must* modify the nodes, you'll need to be a bit more careful that you don't modify anything you shouldn't be. Try using the method I proposed as a template.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeLists(head1, head2):

  if not head1:
      return head2

  elif not head2:
      return head1

  if head1.data <= head2.data:
      res = head1
      res.next = mergeLists(head1.next, head2)
  else:
      res = head2
      res.next = mergeLists(head1, head2.next)

  return res
```